# Balancing block elements like lines of text in print

Tags: css

I would like to achieve a result similar to balancing text lines in print but for block elements. Say a collection of 50/50px boxes in a 300/100px container. Floating the boxes within the container will make them fill up one "row", then wrap onto the next one like this:

```
[1][2][3][4][5][6]
[7]
```

I would like them to "wrap" in a more balanced way:

```
[1][2][3][4]
[5][6][7]
```

or even better, have them "wrap" at every column filling up space as they go:

```
[1][3][5][7]
[2][4][6]
```

I figured you can do this with **CSS columns** but it feels like a hack because the container element need to be `float:left` or `display:inline-block` to force columns to stick together, it needs a constrained height etc. I have added a snippet for reference.

Is there a more genuine CSS way to achieve this?

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block; /*Needs this so make colums stick together*/
  columns: 100px;
  column-gap: 0;
  height: 200px; 
}

.wrap>div {
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  background: red;
  /* styling only */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>
  <div>2Mauris eu risus.</div>
  <div>3Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</div>
  <div>4Consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>
  <div>5Eu risus.</div>
  <div>6Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</div>
  <div>7Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div>8Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div>9Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `flexbox` solution: Using `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent element you can make the items wrap from top to bottom and fill another column once the column is filled.

This is the code to get flexbox working:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
```

And here's a demo:

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.box { 
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maharkus, to my shame I didn't try this obvious solution :( However, how about having items align to the right as text lines do? `align-content: flex-end;` would align the whole block of items to the right BUT not the items themselves. Try this on your code snipped with just 9 items to see what I mean.

Comment: The answer is `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`. This will align items to the right with a visual effect similar to text-align:right.